# react-styled-flexboxgrid different config for different viewport

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, next.js

I'm using this grid library in project https://github.com/yldio/joyent-react-styled-flexboxgrid and I would like to add 3 different configs for 3 different screen sizes (different gutterWidth and columns count).

In doc I see only possibility to create one config and pass it through theme. 
Is anybody here who knows any solution or any other library that meets my requirement.

Edit: Project uses NextJS for SSR.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you'd use the `ThemeProvider` and change the `theme` prop based on the screen width.

```
import React from 'react'

import {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components'
import {Grid, Col, Row} from 'react-styled-flexboxgrid'

const theme = {
  flexboxgrid: {
    // Defaults
    gridSize: 12, // columns
    gutterWidth: 1, // rem
    outerMargin: 2, // rem
    mediaQuery: 'only screen',
    container: {
      sm: 46, // rem
      md: 61, // rem
      lg: 76  // rem
    },
    breakpoints: {
      xs: 0,  // em
      sm: 48, // em
      md: 64, // em
      lg: 75  // em
    }
  }
}

const sizedTheme = 
    (typeof window !== 'undefined') && 
    (window.innerWidth < 500) ? { ...theme, gutterWidth: .5 } : theme;

const App = props =>
  <ThemeProvider theme={sizedTheme}>
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={6} md={3}>Hello, world!</Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

Something like this, adjusted to your goals.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are using nextjs in project so it returns 'window is undefined'

Comment: This was really meant as pseudocode, as I didn't/don't have the logic you need to determine the different screen sizes. There's libraries that can take care of it for you if you need. Edited the code to fix your window is undefined error due to nextjs.